# SIM900 Data usage Get Vs Post

Tags: get, put, sim900

I am using a Sim900 to send data to a web server from 5 sensors by calling:

```
http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/script.php?x=23.5&y=21.7 etc. etc.
```

This data then gets placed in a SQL database using PHP. The page is empty except for html headers and the short PHP script.

Each upload is using 200kb… does this sound about right for such a small amount of data?

Would using a POST script use less data or is it much the same?

Many thanks

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, uploading 200k is far too much,it should be less than 1k providing that your data from 5 sensors is less than 100 or 200 bytes.
Using POST will not change the amount, it will only make the data not displayed in the address.
You need to explain a bit more how you send the data with SIM900.